# Why did my username change to a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae?

Tags: bug, support

All the other Stack Exchange sites link to the same username, but for some reason the AI site changed my username to a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae.

Why did that happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135178/154443 - you should add the [tag:bug] tag

Comment: Does manually editing your profile to fix the name work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Rory Alsop, you've run into [this Stack Exchange bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135178/295684) or something related. You can manually fix your profile by [editing it on this site](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current), or by opening your profile settings on a different site and choosing *Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities*.